# Firebase Order By a Date Value from Today Doesn't Work

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How can I fetch data ordered by a date field value? I want to show all events based on their **starts** field value from now()? I didn't think it will be that hard but I can't get it to properly work.

My firebase data is:

```
    "events" : {
      "-KwX5oG6TYNWWhLYC5rx" : {
        "ends" : "2018-01-04T23:30:47.071Z",
        "starts" : "2018-01-02T23:30:47.062Z",
        "title" : "Event 1" 
      },
      "-L0Id2D34D2Sd2T5oyXX" : {
        "ends" : "2017-12-27T23:30:39.566Z", 
        "starts" : "2017-12-26T23:30:39.552Z",
        "title" : "Event 2"
      }
    }
```

The code to query firebase data:

```
  const today = new Date().toISOString(); 
  const ref = FirebaseRef.child("events").orderByChild('starts').startAt(today);

  return ref.on('value', (snapshot) => {
    const events = snapshot.val() || {};

    // DO SOMETHING
  });
```

I tried storing data as Unix timestamp as well instead of ISO string and still didn't work.

Comment: What's wrong with the result when you run that code?

Comment: Order by is ascending only. It appears you are passing in "today" which would return nothing unless you have days in the future. To order descending, you would need to get all of the values and sort them in a JavaScript function.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen what I see is a list that is not sorted. The events are not showing in descending nor ascending order.

Comment: @SynchroDynamic I do have days in the future as you can see in my example data I used. I do want to have my dates showing in ASC order - Dec 17, 18, 19 etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely the problem is caused by the fact that you do `snapshot.val()` on the query result. When you request ordered data from the Firebase Database, you get back three things: the keys, the values, and the order of the items.

When you call `val()` on a snapshot you get back a JSON representation of the value, which has room for only the keys and the values. And since the order of properties in a JSON object is undefined, the order of your results is undefined (though most browsers show them ordered by key).

To solve this problem, use `Snapshot.forEach()` to iterate over the result in the snapshot:

```
return ref.on('value', (snapshot) => {
  var events = [];
  snapshot.forEach((child) => {
   events.push(child.val());
  });
  console.log(events);
});
```

Comment: Looks like this works! I found a little syntax error where the '=>' is missing i.e. (child) => {} etc. Other than that so far so good. Thanks Frank.

Comment: Thanks for catching! I've been sloppy with my fat arrows this week. :-)

Comment: Awesome solution!